# Pencil & paper spyfall

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pen-and-paper

As a followup to previously asked question: [What's a good strategy for the game "spyfall"?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48162/whats-a-good-strategy-for-the-game-spyfall)

I was wondering if we could build a pencil & paper solution for the problem resistant against pencil & paper attacker.

$k$ players know a secret integer location $[1-30]$ and another (spy) does not. Those who know the secret want to find the spy without letting the spy find the secret. The algorithm proposed by Thomas Pornin in answer to previous question is secure against even powerful attackers. Yet I do see a reasonable way to size it down so as the main flow can be done on pencil & paper in a short time. 
The naive solution of publishing a random $r$ and $H(r+loc)$ could possibly be implemented in pencil & paper (assuming a reasonable pencil & paper hashing exists) but it gives the attacker only a $\times 30$ penalty compared to the legitimate players.

What kind of pencil & paper primitives are there we could use? What are reasonable examples?

Is there a good group with hard discrete logarithms suitable for pencil & paper? 
Can we get a better the $\times 30$ while still remain simple? If we move from a factor of $30$ to a factor of even a few hundred I would consider that success.

Comment: The factor $\times 30$ is based on the fact that the spy only has to check $30$ locations. Changing the complexity of the hash doesn't change that. If the input space for a deterministic function has $X$ possiblities, then checking all $X$ of them always reveals the correct input.

Comment: If the spy has to check 30 locations, won't it be very obvious that he's doing that? I'd call it a "timing attack", as it will take the spy a lot more time to verify the hash than it'd take your other players.  Granted, this is not a very cryptographic approach...

Comment: Unless we put a strict turn time limit and assume equall computational ability by all players this won't work. After the first valid player reveals a hash the spy will make a winning move. With expected effort only 15 times more than a valid player. We should make the attacker effort impractical even for an efficient player.